# QT designer layout inside layout

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

I am not able to design below layout in qt -designer

So under main window , we have one horizontal Layout that have two vertical Layout and each vertical Layout have.

1. one horizontal Layout that contains combo box and push button
2. And another Listview widget

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to do? What is not working?

Comment: The layouts are getting overlap and I m not able to design as mentioned above.

Comment: Provide us the .ui file you've created so far and, possibly, an image of the expected result.

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't include any information about what steps you followed in trying to create this layout and what the final result was, it's impossible to tell where things go wrong. However, to create the layout as described in the post, you could do the following.

### Step 1: Add widgets to form

In a new form in Qt Designer, roughly place the widgets where you want them to be in the final layout.

[image: step one]

### Step 2: Add widgets to layouts

Add widgets to layouts starting with the deepest nested widgets. In this case that would be the comboboxes and push buttons. To add a push-button and combobox to a layout, select both push-button and combobox, either in the layout itself or in the object inspector, right-click on the selection and select lay out > lay out horizontally in the context menu.

[image: step 2a]

Repeat these steps for the other widgets and layouts. When adding the horizontal layout and the list view to a vertical layout, make sure you select the layout and not one of the widgets in the layout:

[image: step 2a]

### Step 3: Set layout of main window

To set the layout of the main window, right-click either anywhere in the main area of the form outside of any child widget or on the MainWindow node in the object inspector and select layout > lay out horizontally. This should result in something like this

[image: final layout]

And the object tree in the object inspector will look something like this

[image: final object tree]

Comment: Thank you my friend. I was trying top to bottom approach. Like I added a layout and then added the elements so layout were not working